# How to get list of pages that a user is admin of. FQL query on page_admin does not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have tried using the fql tool on facebook and the sample query on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/,

Used this query as follows:

```
SELECT page_id, type from page_admin WHERE uid=me()
```

No result is returned. My Facebook account has 2 pages, and there is no result for the above query.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not having extended permission of [manage_pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) that's why you are getting blank result. Take the permission and get your desired result